# "ERROR: Unable to initialize coordinate transformation" when reprojecting from one CRS to another CRS in a different mapset

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis

I am trying to reproject a global raster (this: https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/wildareas-v3-2009-human-footprint/data-download, I named it HFI) from Mollweide (its projection) to LAEA3035 and clip it to Europe.
Usually, these are the steps I follow:

- I create a location with the same coordinate system of the file (in
  this case, I selected "choose the coordinate system from a referenced
  file", and used this raster as reference),
- switch to the Location LAEA3035, where I set the region and resolution:
  `g.region -p res=1000 raster=myEuropeRaster`

  `projection: 99 (ETRS89_LAEA_Europe) zone:       0 datum:      etrs89 ellipsoid:  grs80 north:      6824829.90382694 south:      1385914.39679116 west:       944055.47446584 east:       7602904.43906583 nsres:      999.98446535 ewres:      999.97731861 rows:       5439 cols:       6659 cells:      36218301`
- create a mask `r.mask raster=myEuropeRaster`
- run `r.proj location=MOLL mapset=PERMANENT input=HFI output=HFI`

It isn't working. First it throws two warnings:

`WARNING: proj_trans() failed: acos/asin: |arg| >1.+1e-14`

`WARNING: proj_create() failed for '(null)'`

and then an error:

`ERROR: Unable to initialize coordinate transformation`

This is the selected PROJ pipeline that appears:

```
Selected PROJ pipeline:
+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000
+y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
+ellps=WGS84
```

I searched online but couldn't find much information on how to solve this issue... I am using GRASS 7.8.6 on a server running Ubuntu 18.04.6 fro a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: The LAEA3035 mapset should be in its own, separate  location, based on EPSG 3035.

Comment: Yes, I have a different mapset in a different location based on EPSG 3035 (it is when I wrote "switch to the LAEA3035 mapset"). `g.region -p` output says `projection: 99 (ETRS89_LAEA_Europe)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the extent of the original human footprint raster. It must be beyond the extent that is within the bounds of ETRS (EPSG:3035)

Here's how I worked it out:

- First I created a Mollweide location (as you already did), based on the downloaded human-footprint raster. And I imported that raster.
- Then I made another location (again, you already did this), based on EPSG:3035.
- Now I set the computational region to some "reasonable" bounds:

  micha@RMS$ g.region -ap 
  projection: 99 (ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe) 
  zone:       0 
  datum:      etrs89 
  ellipsoid:  grs80 
  north:      5600000 
  south:      0 
  west:       800000 
  east:       8500000 
  nsres:      1000 
  ewres:      1000 
  rows:       5600 
  cols:       7700 
  cells:      43120000

(Note that the resolution is set to match the original human footprint raster, 1000m.)

- Now I was able to reproject the Mollweide raster, while limited to the computational region.

HTH

[image: Projected result]

Comment: Hi Micha, I tried to set your same computational region (`g.region n=5600000 s=0 e=8500000 w=800000 res=1000 -ap`, resolution is `1000`) and reproject the raster from the Mollweide location (`r.proj --o location=MOLL mapset=PERMANENT input=HFI output=HFI`) but I get again the same problem. I also tried with different global raster (Mollweide projection) and the problem persist.

Comment: P.S.: in Mollweide location I also tried to clip HFI raster to myEuropeRaster, and reproject the clipped raster to EPSG:3035 location - it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas :-(.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Micha. I resolved using gdalwarp: I reprojected from Mollweide to WGS84, and then cropped to Europe while reprojecting into LAEA3035. But still couldn't understand the problem outlined in my question.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. And I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: If you want to carry on with the issue, try reporting on the grass-users maillist. Include your  commands and the error you got.